# Highlight 'Cursor' in Vim using Terminal.app

Tags: macos, vim, terminal.app

When I'm using Vim in Terminal.app it becomes very hard to se the characters under the cursor. In Terminal.app I can only specify the cursor color but not the color of cursor text like in Iterm2 for example.

I've tried to use Vims `highlight Cursor` to change this but nothing changes.

Q: So why not use Iterm2?

A: I don't need the tab and pane features because I use tmux windows and panes. If I use `tail` to show any log file it has a smother rendering. Same when I scroll in Vim. And when i type text quickly Iterm2 renders the text slower than Terminal.app. So if I can fix this little issue I would be happy.

Screenshoot (the text is hard to see under the cursor):

[image: screenshoot]

Comment: Simple solution: set your cursor color to one that works.

Comment: Would [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/) work better (!= iTerm2)?  Btw for vim on Mac I recommend [MacVim](http://macvim.org/OSX/index.php) which is like `gvim` in Linux, using its own window.

Comment: @romainl I've tried to find a cursor color which should work with all other colors in Solaried colorsheme but without success.

Comment: @janos Thanks for the tip about using old iTerm. Just tried it out but  it didn't had the features I need.
When I work i like to have 
1. xterm-256color terminal, 
2. tmux, 
3. vim, 
4. Solarized colorschema.

I've tried a few times to use MacVim instead of Vim in the terminal. But I miss Tmux to much and I jump between bash and vim all the time.